# What is "debugger" in a lexical sense?

Tags: javascript, google-chrome

I just discovered the `debugger` keyword or whatever it is for JavaScript development, and I'm not clear what it is. Certainly it's not an expression, it has no value. But do I need to put a semi-colon after it? What is it defined as part of? I mean, it's technically like an addition to the language in the chrome runtime, isn't it?

(I know what it *does*, I just don't know the details of its implementation and how I would explain its lexical nature to someone else.)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It's actually described in [**ES5 standard**](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/5.1/#sec-12.15) - and yes, it's a `statement`:

> **Syntax**
>
> *DebuggerStatement :*
>
> `debugger;`
>
> **Semantics**
>
> Evaluating the `DebuggerStatement` production may allow an
>   implementation to cause a breakpoint when run under a debugger. If a
>   debugger is not present or active this statement has no observable
>   effect.
>
> It is evaluated as follows:
>
> - If an implementation defined debugging facility is available and enabled, then
>
>   - Perform an implementation defined debugging action.
>   - Let result be an implementation defined Completion value.
> - Else
>
>   - Let result be (`normal, empty, empty`). Return result.

As a sidenote, most modern browsers - not only Chrome - support this functionality.